# AS3 CHANGING the order of an Array - eliminate zero?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have an array of 10 items.

```
var myArray:Array = ["One", "Two", "Three","Four", "Five", "Six","Seven", "Eight", "Nine","Ten"];
```

I would like to keep these same ten items but want the array to start with 1 and not 0.

For example if I called.

```
trace(myArray[1]); // this should display "One";
```

if did this...

```
trace(myArray[7]); // this should display "Seven";
```

What SIMPLE function could I write to change this order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add "Zero" as the first element of that array. Should do :)

Comment: Clever workaround. This can be done with code: myArray.unshift("Zero")

Comment: Great idea but I need ten items. :) That will give me 11 :) I need it for other purposes in code later. Actually, that worked. It would be nice to have only ten in there.. but that did work. :)

Comment: You can't have 10 items in a solid array with the last item's index be 10. This is a feature of a zero-based array addressing. You can, however, declare a constant or two describing the actually used part of the array. Or, you initialize the array with `myArray[1]="One";` etc, but in the end that array's length will still be 11, with 0th element existing but undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```
function returnArrayVal(i:uint):*{  
    return myArray[--i];
}
trace(returnArrayVal(5));
```